# How do i add ggplot facet_grid() into a barchart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am very new to R and coding in general
I have a data frame similar to this but with a lot more rows:

```
weekofmonth <- c('week1','week2','week3','week4','week','week2','week3','week4','week1','week2','week3','week4','week1','week2','week3','week4','week1','week2','week3','week4')
arrival_delayed <- c('Yes','No','No','Yes','Yes','No','No','No','Yes','Yes','No','Yes','No','Yes','No','Yes','No','Yes','No','Yes')
quarters <- c('Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4','Q2','Q3','Q4','Q1','Q3','Q4','Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4','Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4','Q1','Q2')

data<- data.frame(weekofmonth,arrival_delayed,quarters)
```

I have managed to create a stacked bar chart for the data$quarter == 'Q1', where the x-axis is the 'weeks of the month' and the y-axis is the 'percentage delayed'.

I used the packages ggplot2 and dplyr.

```
weeks_1stQuarter <-data  %>%
  filter(quarters == 'Q1')%>%
  mutate(weekofmonth = factor(x= weekofmonth, levels = c('week1','week2','week3','week4'), labels = c('1st Week','2nd Week','3rd Week','4th Week'))) %>%
  count(weekofmonth, arrival_delayed) %>%       
  group_by(weekofmonth) %>%
  mutate(pct= prop.table(n) * 100) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  aes(weekofmonth, pct, fill=arrival_delayed) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  ylab("Percentage of Flights") +
  xlab("Week of the Month") +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0(sprintf("%1.1f", pct),"%")),position=position_stack(vjust=0.5)) +
  ggtitle("percentage delay per week of the month (1st Quarter)") +
  coord_flip()+
  theme_bw()

plot(weeks_1stQuarter)
```

However, I am trying the add the facet_grid() into the code to show 4 different graphs for Q1, Q2, Q3, and Q4 respectively.

This is what I came up with:

```
weeks_all_Quarters <-data  %>%
  mutate(quarters = factor(x=quarters, levels=c('Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4'), labels=c('1st Quarter','2nd Quarter','3rd Quarter','4th Quarter'))) %>%
  mutate(weekofmonth = factor(x= weekofmonth, levels = c('week1','week2','week3','week4'), labels = c('1st Week','2nd Week','3rd Week','4th Week'))) %>%
  count(weekofmonth, arrival_delayed) %>%       
  group_by(weekofmonth) %>%
  mutate(pct= prop.table(n) * 100) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  aes(weekofmonth, pct, fill=arrival_delayed) +
  facet_grid(.~quarters)+
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  ylab("Percentage of Flights") +
  xlab("Week of the Month") +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0(sprintf("%1.1f", pct),"%")),position=position_stack(vjust=0.5)) +
  ggtitle("percentage delay per week of the month (1st Quarter)") +
  coord_flip()+
  theme_bw()

plot(weeks_all_Quarters)
```

there was an error stating:

```
Error: At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: `quarters`.
* Plot is missing `quarters`
* Layer 1 is missing `quarters`
* Layer 2 is missing `quarters`
```

I am not very sure what I did wrong.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Run your code up through the line `mutate(pct= prop.table(n) * 100)`: you no longer have a column `quarters`. You lost it in the `count` operation. Maybe you wanted to include that as one of your grouping columns to count by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you should use `add_count()` in place of `count()` in your code.  The line `count(weekofmonth, arrival_delayed)` results in a data frame that includes a count (new column = `n`) of those two columns, but *drops all other columns* - including "quarters".

Using `add_count()` will add the tally column ("n"), but not drop the others.

You'll see the difference if you output the data frame from your original code:

```
data  %>%
  mutate(quarters = factor(x=quarters, levels=c('Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4'), labels=c('1st Quarter','2nd Quarter','3rd Quarter','4th Quarter'))) %>%
  mutate(weekofmonth = factor(x= weekofmonth, levels = c('week1','week2','week3','week4'), labels = c('1st Week','2nd Week','3rd Week','4th Week'))) %>%
  count(weekofmonth, arrival_delayed)
```

Compared with `add_count()`:

```
data  %>%
  mutate(quarters = factor(x=quarters, levels=c('Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4'), labels=c('1st Quarter','2nd Quarter','3rd Quarter','4th Quarter'))) %>%
  mutate(weekofmonth = factor(x= weekofmonth, levels = c('week1','week2','week3','week4'), labels = c('1st Week','2nd Week','3rd Week','4th Week'))) %>%
  add_count(weekofmonth, arrival_delayed)
```

The resulting plot if you make that change looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I think they should still use `count`, but add `quarters` to it. Your plot doesn't add up the groups, which is why you've got several percentages smashed together (turn on a border around the bars to see)